# awk ward gps monitoring

Tags: awk, gps-time

I have a little Raspberry Pi monitoring things like temperature, wind and pressure. Now our dear russians have started to tamper with GPS in my neighbourhood and I saw that our authorities where rather slow to react.
I have an old GPS pl2303 GPS dongle which I think could be good to keep a timely check on local GPS behaviour.
My problem is the following:

Using the NMEA-stream from gpsd and gpspipe I try to extract the coordinates with awk:

```
gpspipe -r |grep GPGGA
```

gives me

......
$GPGGA,225842.00,5919.2601,N,01758.1669,E,1,06,2.00,19.55,M,24.163,M,,*5
.....

but

```
gpspipe -r |grep GPGGA|awk -F, '{ print $3 } { print $5 }'
```

gives me nothing.
If I, however, save the output from gpspipe -r to a file g

```
cat g|grep GPGGA|awk -F, '{ print $3 } { print $5 }'
```

gives me
...
5919.2689
01758.1838
...
which is what I want.
Why doesn't awk produce the desired output when directly fed with the NMEA stream? What have I missed?
H

Comment: Please take a look at [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 2):

Probably you are not waiting long enough.

If your `grep` has a `--line-buffered` option that should help:

```
gpspipe -r |
grep --line-buffered GPGGA |
awk '{ print $3; print $5 }'
```

Or if your system has `stdbuf` you can try:

```
gpspipe -r |
stdbuf -oL -- grep GPGGA |
awk '{ print $3; print $5 }'
```

(or `... stdbuf -o0 ...`)

When using `awk`, `grep` is not required:

```
gpspipe -r |
awk '/GPGGA/ { print $3; print $5; fflush() }'
```

---

**explanation**

I am guessing that `gpspipe -r` produces output continuously until stopped. If that is the case, your problem is probably that when `grep` output is fed into a pipe, it is buffered. Until the buffer is full, `awk` does not receive any input.

You can get an idea with:

```
# prints immediately
seq 100000 |
grep . |
awk '(NR%10000)==0{printf"."}END{print""}'
```

```
# prints after a delay
(
    # not enough to fill buffer
    seq 10
    # wait
    sleep 5
    # enough to fill buffer
    seq 10000
) |
grep . |
awk '(NR%10000)==0{printf"."}END{print""}'
```

Comment: yes, no newlines would be a big problem

Comment: Thanks for a very clear and complete answer. It slowly became clear also to me that there were no newlines. I did solve the problem by giving gpspipe the -n option and using the more frequent GPRMC NMEA tag:                                                      
  gpspipe -r -n 20|grep -m 1 GPRMC|awk -F, '{ print $4 " " $6 }'

Answer (score 0):

In our bash world streams without newlines aren't uncommon. Examples are ls and cat that may send you long lineless streams. Sometimes the use of named pipes is a remedy. This particular problem can be handled with:

```
~$ mkfifo gpsfifo; gpspipe -r -o gpsfifo & cat gpsfifo|awk -F, '/GPGGA/ { print $3 " " $5; }'
```

[1] 57231
5919.2625 01758.1808
5919.2625 01758.1808
5919.2625 01758.1808
5919.2625 01758.1808
5919.2625 01758.1808
5919.2621 01758.1765
....
....